# Multicast entitlement not installing

Tags: ios, xcode, multicast, entitlements

I have been given the multicast entitlement for an IOS app and have been using it during development without any problems. When I try to archive the app for distribution I get a warning that the entitlement is part of my team's provisioning profile but is missing from the .entitlements file (it's not missing). Any ideas on what might cause it to not get picked up during the archive process but still be included during debug and development?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get the archiver to recognize the entitlements file by removing its path and re-entering it in the build settings (under code signing entitlements). This took several tries but it eventually worked.